# Get audio music as a byte array when Mediaplayer start() without record

Tags: android

I want to get audio as a byte array when android `MediaPlayer.start()` hit. It is not matter `medipalyer.source("url/sd card")`. Noted that without record audio by `Audiosource.MIC`

Thank you

Comment: what is your actual requirement as we can convert the file into bytes and then provide into to mediaplayer.

Comment: Suppose i have a file when mediaplayer play the file i need byte of array. That means if mediaplayer seek into some millisecond i need thats sound in byte array (without recording)